# Join returning zero elements where it should not

Tags: mysql, join

The below SQL statement looks for friendship between two user elements, by querying friendship table using users' profile_id#s, but the line I recently added to the working statement was `LEFT OUTER JOIN block_user_filters AS blockedusers on blockedusers.profile_id_1 = 'abcde2'` where I want to see if user abcde2 has blocked anyone, and if so I want to filter these friendships from the tableon the where clause `LEFT OUTER JOIN block_user_filters AS blockedusers on blockedusers.profile_id_1 = 'abcde2'` where I have the block table populated with a block row of user abcde2 to another friended user element, however the whole statement is returning 0 rows. Please help me fix this if you can. Thank you

```
SELECT  
  users1.username AS firstusername, 
  users2.username AS secondusername,
  users1.profile_id AS firstprofid,
  users2.profile_id AS secondprofid,
  users1.picup AS firstpicup, 
  users2.picup AS secondpicup
FROM  `users` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  `friendship` 
        ON friendship.profile_id_1 = users.profile_id OR friendship.profile_id_2 = users.profile_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users1 ON users1.profile_id = friendship.profile_id_1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users2 ON users2.profile_id = friendship.profile_id_2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN block_user_filters AS blockedusers on blockedusers.profile_id_1 = 'abcde2'
  WHERE users.profile_id = 'abcde2' and blockedusers.profile_id_1 != 'abcde2' and friendship.state = 1 limit 6
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the answer and comments, but unfortunately even after trying is null, it's still returns zero rows, I was thinking that I should be checking blockedusers.profile_id_2 instead and separate the two possibilities of friendship table's first user existance (in either friendship.profid_1 or _2), and combine them with a UNION, but this has even weirder results, I just need to get my head together...

```
SELECT users1.username AS firstusername, users.username AS secondusername, 
users1.profile_id AS firstprofid, users.profile_id AS secondprofid,
users1.picup AS firstpicup, users.picup AS secondpicup
FROM  `users` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `friendship` ON friendship.profile_id_2 = users.profile_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users1 ON users1.profile_id = friendship.profile_id_1
LEFT OUTER JOIN block_user_filters AS blockedusers on blockedusers.profile_id_1 = 'abcde2'
WHERE users.profile_id = 'abcde2' and blockedusers.profile_id_2 != friendship.profile_id_1 and friendship.state = 1
UNION
SELECT users.username AS firstusername, users.username AS secondusername, 
users.profile_id AS firstprofid, users2.profile_id AS secondprofid,
users.picup AS firstpicup, users2.picup AS secondpicup
FROM  `users` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `friendship` ON friendship.profile_id_1 = users.profile_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users2 ON users2.profile_id = friendship.profile_id_2
LEFT OUTER JOIN block_user_filters AS blockedusers on blockedusers.profile_id_1 = 'abcde2'
WHERE users.profile_id = 'abcde2' and blockedusers.profile_id_2 != friendship.profile_id_2 and friendship.state = 1
```

Comment: Please consider using smaller result sets rather than joining a bunch of tables and then nonchalantly throwing in `LIMIT 6`

Comment: Just doing a second query to find blocked users is likely both faster and easier to maintain than this query with all the `LEFT JOIN` clauses.

Comment: The reason you are returning zero records is because you are joining the blockedusers table ON profile_id_1 = 'abcde2' and then in your where clause you are filtering out blocked users with profile_id_1 = 'abcde2'.  Not sure what you are trying to do there, but you will always return zero records.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, @Cfreak I could separate them but it wouldn't be faster I guess due to my application's model architecture, but I agree this type of join statements in itself can be made much faster, for now I'm just hacking together a solution until another iteration of refactorisation.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO how do you suggest I could reduce the result sets? Logic is, I am trying to get friends of this chappy abcde2 and at the same time filter the results according to a filter table so I can't think of a lesser statement?

Comment: @Tom thank you, I realised that after posting the question, what I was trying was not to get any results when the abcde2 user has anyone in the blocked list.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you are looking for.  The last line of the last join should match on the second ID in the friendship.  If there is a match, it will be omitted by the `blockedusers.profile_id_1 IS NULL` criteria in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT users1.username   AS firstusername, 
       users2.username   AS secondusername, 
       users1.profile_id AS firstprofid, 
       users2.profile_id AS secondprofid, 
       users1.picup      AS firstpicup, 
       users2.picup      AS secondpicup 

FROM   friendship 

       LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users1 
                    ON users1.profile_id = friendship.profile_id_1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users2 
                    ON users2.profile_id = friendship.profile_id_2 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN block_user_filters AS blockedusers 
                    ON  blockedusers.profile_id_1 = 'abcde2'
                    AND blockedusers.profile_id_2 IN (users1.profile_id, users2.profile_id)

WHERE  (friendship.profile_id_1 = 'abcde2' or friendship.profile_id_2 = 'abcde2')
       AND friendship.state = 1 
       AND blockedusers.profile_id_1 IS NULL 

LIMIT  6
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your where clause.  `blockedusers.profile_id_1 != 'abcde2'` was filtering out all results.  Since if there was a match in the blockedusers table, the value of profile_id_1 was 'abcde2'.  If there was no match, the value returned for that field would be NULL, and the WHERE clause would fail also.  Check to see if profile_id_1 IS NULL instead to get friends that are not blocked.

```
SELECT users1.username   AS firstusername, 
       users2.username   AS secondusername, 
       users1.profile_id AS firstprofid, 
       users2.profile_id AS secondprofid, 
       users1.picup      AS firstpicup, 
       users2.picup      AS secondpicup 
FROM   users 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN friendship 
                    ON friendship.profile_id_1 = users.profile_id 
                        OR friendship.profile_id_2 = users.profile_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users1 
                    ON users1.profile_id = friendship.profile_id_1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users2 
                    ON users2.profile_id = friendship.profile_id_2 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN block_user_filters AS blockedusers 
                    ON blockedusers.profile_id_1 = 'abcde2' 
WHERE  users.profile_id = 'abcde2' 
       AND blockedusers.profile_id_1 IS NULL 
       AND friendship.state = 1 
LIMIT  6
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, please see my edit statement as my answer didn't fit here

Comment: Ok.  I think I might know what's going on.  Does the blockedusers table have a profile_id_2 which contains the blocked user?  blockedusers.profile_id_1 is the person doing the blocking, correct?

Comment: I worked around it by using a second query with the results of the first one with friendship information by the way, but this query, if was right, would be more efficient IMO

Comment: I posted another answer to this.  Check it out.